# How to delete entire directory fast in under 1 hour that contains millions of files and nearly 18TB of data?

Tags: centos, files, partition, delete

My backup program backed up entire other drives multiple times by accident to one of my large drives and therefore hogged the entire drive. I already have backed up to another drive what I need from this drive, but turns out that due to this full drive, a backup wasn't done on this drive in 2 years, so I don't need any of these old backups.

`rm -rf` is not practical and might take days or weeks at the rate it's going. It's simply not acceptable. I figured formatting the drive will be faster than deleting it since I don't need anything on the drive now. Is that the only way? If so how should I do this (what commands will be most efficient to delete partition and recreate), or if there is a reasonable way to destroy 18TB and millions of files without formatting the drive, I would prefer that, because formatting a drive is extremely risky (could accidentally delete another drive with one typo).

What is the best solution here to destroy these 18TB and millions of files on the whole drive?

Answer (score 2):

If there's nothing else important on the filesystem then just re-format it.  As always with anything potentially destructive, be extremely careful and check (and double- and triple-check) your command line before you hit enter.   Carelessness is the problem, not the command being run.

If there is other important data on the filesystem then make a backup of that data and restore it after the format.

BTW, you might want to take the time to consider all the options for the filesystem's new format.  First figure out what it is mostly going to be used for, and then figure out which filesystem is the most appropriate for that use-case.  You might want to format it with XFS or btrfs or ZFS rather than, say, ext4.

If you don't want to backup/reformat/restore (e.g. because you want regularly scheduled backups to keep happening while the unwanted files are being deleted) then rename the directory and re-create it with the same owner, group, and permissions, and then delete the renamed directory.   For example (as root, using GNU `chown` and `chmod`):

```bash
mv bigdata bigdata.old &&
  mkdir bigdata &&
  chown --reference=bigdata.old bigdata &&
  chmod --reference=bigdata.old bigdata &&
  rm -rf bigdata.old
```

This won't be any faster, but it will allow the drive to continue being used while the old directory is being deleted.

Note: this assumes that the directory you want to delete is a sub-directory of the mount-point, not the mount-point itself.  If it is the mount-point, then re-formatting is your best option.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to delete and recreate a partition just to reformat it.   You only need to re-partition a drive if you want to change the size or number or order of the partitions. or switch from MBR to GPT partitioning.

Comment: If your suggestion was to reformat, you have failed to provide the commands to do it. The only command you provided was the one I already wrote in the question and said isn't feasible. If you edit this to tell me how to reformat, then I may accept the answer. Also, moving it AND removing it would be double the time! That's the OPPOSITE of what I want to do.

Comment: 1. you didn't provide enough details (device name, current filesystem type) to provide a formatting command.  It's going to be one of the `mkfs.xxx` commands, where xxx is the fs type.  2. moving and removing will NOT double the time.  Renaming a file or directory takes no time at all (unless you're moving it to another filesystem).  3. I don't like your entitled, whingey tone so I'm not going to waste any more of my valuable time on your question.